# Overlay does not work if it is used over embeded video [Firefox]

Tags: css, firefox, html5-video

Please checkout the following code it works perfectly in chrome but not in mozilla firefox. Please help me sort out this problem for firefox.

I want a `marquee` tag to float over video, ticker like.

I have tried using "relative" and "absolute" position, but somehow z-index over embeded video dosen't seem to work.

[Here is the code](http://jsfiddle.net/j77JP/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the `?wmode=opaque` at the end of the embed "link".

#### Check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j77JP/4/)

Your **URL** : http://www.youtube.com/embed/WfDK-vfPwag?wmode=opaque

also Use **`<iframe>`** tag to solve this problem and support all Broswer.

#### your Updated code

```
<iframe width="80%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/WfDK-vfPwag?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: note just for you info if the link is a video link(i.e. http://www.youtube.com/v/WfDK-vfPwag?wmode=opaque) instead of embeded video link(i.e http://www.youtube.com/embed/WfDK-vfPwag?wmode=opaque) that z-index property gets ignored